# How to return variables from PyQt5 UI to Main function - Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

I have design a customized formlayout ui using pyqt5 and want to import variables back to the main function for further execution of the main function.

I have tried many ways to get the return values from the main function when the "OK" button has clicked but unable to get the variables from the main function.

Can you please guide me, how can i get the variables from the pyqt5 formlayout ui to main function -

Here is the Code of PyQt5 FormLayout UI function -

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
        QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
        QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
        QVBoxLayout,QCheckBox)

import sys

app = QApplication([])

class Dialog(QDialog):  

    def __init__(self,dinput):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox(dinput)        

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)        
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)        

        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout")    


    def accept(self):        
        print(self.linedit1.text())
        print(self.combox1.currentText())        
        print(self.spinbox1.value())       
        self.closeEvent()

    def reject(self):
        print('Cancelled')
        self.closeEvent()

    def getoutput(self):
        return self.linedit1.text()

    def createFormGroupBox(self,dinput):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()

        self.linedit1 = QLineEdit()        
        self.linedit1.setText('TestName')
        layout.addRow(QLabel(dinput[0]), self.linedit1)        
        self.combox1 = QComboBox()
        self.combox1.setToolTip('Hello')
        self.combox1.addItems(['India','France','UK','USA','Germany'])
        layout.addRow(QLabel(dinput[1]), self.combox1)        
        self.spinbox1 = QSpinBox()        
        layout.addRow(QLabel(dinput[2]), self.spinbox1)        
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
```

Main Function is -

```
import os
import sys
import pyformlayout as pyfl

# Staring Functions for Execution

dinput = ['LastName','Country','Age']
# Call the UI and get the inputs
dialog = pyfl.Dialog(dinput)
if(dialog.exec_()):
    TName = dialog.getoutput
    print('------------------')
    print(TName)

# Main Function Continous by getting the inputs
# from UI
```

I am unable to get the desired values to the output function. Even i have used the getoutput function to return the values and get the output to "TName". But i am not able to get the value into the TName variable and nothing is displaying.

The Result i am getting is - (which is basically printing the accept button function but not the TName variable which is returned to Main function.

```
TestName
India
25
```

How can i get the return values from PyQt5 Formlayout UI function to Main function..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, FormLayout is a layout, that is, a class that is responsible for positioning the widgets within a window, so it is irrelevant for these cases. On the other hand, `closeEvent()` should never be invoked, that is a function that serves to handle the closed window event.

Going to the point the accept method is called when Ok is pressed, so it is the right place to get the values so it must be stored in a variable, and then returned in the `get_output()` method:

**pyformlayout.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):  
    def __init__(self, dinput):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox(dinput)        

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)        
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)     

        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout")    

    def createFormGroupBox(self, dinput):
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.linedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('TestName')
        self.combox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combox1.setToolTip('Hello')
        self.combox1.addItems(['India','France','UK','USA','Germany'])
        self.spinbox1 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()  

        for text, w in zip(dinput, (self.linedit1, self.combox1, self.spinbox1)):
            layout.addRow(text, w)     

        self.formGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Form layout")        
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def accept(self):        
        self._output = self.linedit1.text(), self.combox1.currentText(), self.spinbox1.value()    
        super(Dialog, self).accept()

    def get_output(self):
        return self._output
```

And in the file main.py I get the value if only the ok button has been pressed:

**main.py**

```
import pyformlayout as pyfl

# Staring Functions for Execution
dinput = ['LastName','Country','Age']
# Call the UI and get the inputs
dialog = pyfl.Dialog(dinput)
if dialog.exec_() == pyfl.Dialog.Accepted:
    name, item, value = dialog.get_output()
    print(name, item, value)
```